# Scala - Unit doesn't conform to expected type Long (java sql timestamp)

Tags: scala, timestamp

I'm new to Scala and I have been trying to parse JSON strings to Timestamps (of type long). I keep getting following error "Unit doesn't conform to expected type Long" and I haven't got a clue why

```
    import java.sql.Timestamp
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    import java.util.Date

    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    var timestamp: Timestamp = new Timestamp(0)
    var parsedDate: Date = new Date()
    var dateString: String = ""
    var timestampLong: Long = 0

    def extractAscendingTimestamp(element: String): Long = {

       implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
       dateString = parse(element).extract[SheetFedRecord].begin

       try {
           parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString)
           timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime)
           timestampLong = timestamp.getTime.asInstanceOf[Long]
       }
      catch {
           case e: Exception => 0.asInstanceOf[Long]
       }
    }
```

In both try and catch I'm giving the method a "long" variable to return. Could somebody help please?

Comment: use val instead of var where it is possible.
as I understand your logic 
parsedDate, dateString can be val inside function extractAscendingTimestamp. 
timestampLong is not necessary, you can just return last statement timestamp.getTime.asInstanceOf[Long]

Comment: Using `var` is suite discouraged in Scala for such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last statement in yout try catch should be

```
timestamp.getTime.asInstanceOf[Long]
```

instead of

```
timestampLong = timestamp.getTime.asInstanceOf[Long]
```

If you still want to modify the timestampLong variable, then the last statement in yout try catch should become these two lines:

```
timestampLong = timestamp.getTime.asInstanceOf[Long]
timestampLong
```